# Tkinter removing an object from the canvas using delete

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having difficulty understanding how to delete an object from the canvas. A rocket object is created from `Class Rocket` and is just a simple oval. After an event, I'm trying to use the `canvas.delete()` method with the argument set to `rocket` in order to remove this object from the canvas but it doesn't seem to work.

My goal is to create multiple rockets in a list and delete some during the animation.

I have include just main() function. The Class Rocket just creates an oval on the canvas and works fine.

> file: constants.py

```
CANVAS_WIDTH = 600      # Width of drawing canvas in pixels
CANVAS_HEIGHT = 600     # Height of drawing canvas in pixels
ROCKET_SIZE = 30
```

> file: test.py

```
import tkinter
import time
import random
from constants import *
from Rocket import Rocket

def main():
    canvas = make_canvas(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT, 'Fireworks')

    #put a rocket a bottom of canvas
    rocket = Rocket(canvas)
    canvas.update()
    time.sleep(50/50.)  #pause to see the rocket

    # some event occurs (not important for this example)

    canvas.delete(rocket)  #this doesn't make the rocket disappear!
    canvas.update()
    time.sleep(50/50.)

def make_canvas(width, height, title):

    top = tkinter.Tk()
    top.minsize(width=width, height=height)
    top.title(title)
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(top, width=width + 1, height=height + 1)
    canvas.pack()
    return canvas

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> file: Rocket.py

```
import random
from constants import *

class Rocket:
    '''
    This is the blueprint for a new variable type called "Rocket"
    Every rocket has three things: an oval, a change_x and a change_y.
    Every rocket supports the "update" method which will move the rocket one step.
    '''
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        # Starting point - screen bottom with slight angle
        x_1 = random.randint(CANVAS_WIDTH/2 - 50, CANVAS_WIDTH/2 + 50)
        y_1 = CANVAS_HEIGHT - ROCKET_SIZE
        x_2 = x_1 + ROCKET_SIZE
        y_2 = CANVAS_HEIGHT
        self.fill = random.choice(['blue', 'green', 'orange', 'purple', 'red', 'lime'])
        self.oval = canvas.create_oval(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, fill=self.fill, outline=self.fill)
        self.change_x = random.randint(-3, 3)
        self.change_y = random.randint(-15, -5)

    # again, I pass in canvas.
    def update(self, canvas):
        # update a single rocket instance (the one given by self)
        canvas.move(self.oval, self.change_x, self.change_y)
```

Comment: Could you include the code for the Rocket function? It will help to test a solution.

Comment: Thanks! I will edit the original post now.

Comment: You code is not a [mre] because `main()` creates the rocket and then immediately deletes it. Also note that calling `time.sleep()` in a tkinter application halts the `mainloop()` which "hangs" the application for the duration.

Comment: Thanks. I will add a time delay after the rocket is create.  I haven't had an issue with time.sleep() halting the application.

Comment: `canvas.delete()` requires either an item ID (as returned by the various create_XXXX() methods), or a tag name.  You passed an instance of your class, which is not either of these things.  Since you only have a single Canvas item per rocket, you could do `canvas.delete(rocket.oval)` to remove it.  If you ever make your rockets fancier, with multiple drawn items, you will need to generate a unique tag (perhaps "R1", "R2", etc.) and apply it to each of those items, and then use that tag when calling `.delete()`.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the argument from rocket to rocket.get_id which is a new method in the Rocket class that just returns the id for each rocket object created. This is rocket.oval as you so astutely noted. I now understand that the ID for each object is stored in self.oval - I should really change that variable name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After helpful feedback and more research, here is my first solution;

add to Class Rocket the following -

```
    # method to get canvas object id (already assigned to self.oval in constructor)
    def get_id(self):
       return self.oval
```

change the following line:

```
canvas.delete(rocket)
```

in main() to:

```
canvas.delete(rocket.get_id())
```

This also worked for multiple rockets created in a list.

I haven't tried deleting the rocket within the Class Rocket as a method, but this seems like the most elegant solution. Either way, the object ID is the required argument for canvas.delete.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `canvas.delete(rocket)`, tkinter will convert `rocket` to a string before passing it off to the actual delete method. So, you can modify your rocket class to return the canvas object id from the `__str__` method:

```
class Rocket():
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.oval)
```

The downside to this is that it only allows you to have a single canvas element for drawing the rocket. If you have more than just a single object, you can instead have `__str__` return an id, such as "rocket#1", and associate that id with every object that makes up the rocket.

For example, this uses both an oval and square for the rocket:

```
def __init__(self, canvas)
    ...
    self.oval = canvas.create_oval(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, fill=self.fill, outline=self.fill)
    # the id of the oval to create a tag for all rocket pieces
    self.tag = f"rocket#{self.oval}"
    self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.oval, tags=(self.tag,))
    self.square = canvas.create_rectangle(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_1-20, fill="black", tags=(self.tag,))

def __str__(self):
    return self.tag
```

Perhaps a better way would be to give your rocket a `delete` method (or `distruct`!) so that it is responsible for deleting itself.

This requires saving the canvas, and then having the rocket call `self.canvas.delete(self.oval)` when you want the rocket to be destroyed.

```
class Rocket:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        ...

    def destruct(self):
        self.canvas.delete(self.oval)

...
def main():
    ...
    # some event occurs (not important for this example)
    rocket.destruct()
```